# TextBoxes not visible in DataGridview TextBox Column

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

First of all I am totally new to winforms.. I am tryingto display textboxes in datagridview in a column even though I have used TextBoxColumn I am not seeing any textboxes in the Gridview.

**Form Load**

```
dt.Columns.Add("SrNo")
dt.Columns.Add("SecurityName")
dt.Columns.Add("ISIN")
dt.Columns.Add("PriceSource")
dt.Columns.Add("ValuationRate")
dt.Columns.Add("PriceDate")
dt.Columns.Add("GenerateInstruction")
dt.Columns.Add("BalanceType")
dt.Columns.Add("DepositoryHolding")
dt.Columns.Add("EnterQuantity")
dt.Columns.Add("PledgeReferenceNo")
dt.Columns.Add("LockInReleaseDate")
dt.Columns.Add("LockInCode")

dt.Rows.Add("1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

I have added columns through tool tip of DataGridView.

Comment: post code plz, so we can get to see what actually is the problem

Comment: @VladL dt is DataTable

Comment: I am able to see button or combobox when i use DataGridViewButtonColumn or DataGridViewComboBoxColumn but i am not able to find TextBox oupon using DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Comment: @Arbaaz the `TextBox` is just shown when in edit mode. All the cells will be painted in the way of the DGV. Why do you want such a thing? The look and feel of the `TextBox` is even worse than the look and feel of the `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`.

Comment: @KingKing is it possible to display textbox even when DGV is not in edit mode?

Comment: @Arbaaz of course it is BUT the performance may become very poor, because you have to use each `TextBox` for each cell and you need **much** code to deal with user interactivity, that's not recommended at all. If you want the look and feel of the `TextBox` you can try adding code to `CellPainting`.

Comment: @KingKing i just want a DataGridView for data Entry work.. where user can type in stuff and select values from combobox and save it.

Comment: @Arbaaz maybe `DataGridView` is not for your purpose. If you need just some controls, simply design them on a panel or usercontrol, in real project we can design hundreds of such controls. `DataGridView` is just for displaying data in `grid` and allowing user to edit one cell at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2");

        DataRow row;
        row = dt.NewRow();

        row["Column1"] = "Hello";
        row["Column2"] = "World";

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].CellTemplate = cell;
```

Edit: in this way you programmatically define your cell type.

Answer (score 0):

VB SQL OleDB

```
    Dim row As DataRow
    For Each row In dt.Rows
    Dim SrNo,SecurityName As String
    SrNo = row(1).ToString()
    SecurityName= row(2).ToString()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add( SrNo,SecurityName)
    Next
```

You can try this also